# How can I open an *modal* file dialog with IFileOpenDialog?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, openfiledialog

I've been trying to implement a file dialog into my C++ application for a while now, and I achieved good success with the code described in this article (It is german, but the code should be understandable):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ff485843(v=vs.85).aspx

However, using this code in my window class, which is a CDialogImpl, I just can't find out how to make this file picker modal. If I use this code, I can just spawn multiple file picker.

Of course, I could just keep track of the state by adding a member variable representing the state, but it would still not solve the problem of being able to click around in the main window while the dialog is opened.

Is there any way which would allow me to make this window modal? I've been trying to scan through all available methods, but I couldn't find anything. I didn't find any flags which could be passed in the creation, neither any options which I could set after creation.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example you link to is very simple and has no UI other than the file dialog. Your program is more complex, having a window from which the file dialog is invoked.

You need to provide an owner for the file dialog. When you do that the owner is disabled, part of what makes the dialog modal. Failing to pass an owner means that the other windows are not disabled and so still respond to user input.

The example code provides no owner, but since there are no other windows in that program, that is benign. Modality is only meaningful when there are multiple windows.

So, to solve the problem, pass the owner, the handle of your window, to the `Show` method of the file dialog.

Disabling owner windows is one of the key parts of a modal dialog. You will find that any API for modal dialogs expects you to specify an owner. Get into the habit of expecting to provide that ownwr window, and looking for the means to do so.

Comment: This is as simple as it can get. Great explanation!

Comment: @Sossenbinder: Keep in mind, though, that often the API calls use the wrong terminology, and parameters for owner windows are named *"hParent"*.